# Under which dutch taxation scheme does the following activity fall into?

Tags: taxes, netherlands

I am currently living in the Netherlands, but working remote for a non-dutch company from abroad and receiving income from them based on hours worked, on a freelance basis. The contract stipulates that I have to take care of the taxes in my country of residence.

I am confused by the taxation schemes with regards to this situation.  How should I approach the topic of registering this activity and which taxation scheme applies?

Comment: The answer to this question will almost certainly depend on the nationality of the person asking it, as well as the country where the non-Dutch company is located.

Answer (score 1):

If you are not an EU citizen, it is quite likely that you will need a Dutch work permit in order to work in the Netherlands. This is usually something best organised before you actually start to do any work, in case it turns into a bureaucratic nightmare (or an impossibility).

The rules for EU citizens are almost certainly different.

Answer (score 1):

The page of the [Dutch tax authority (belastingdienst)](http://www.belastingdienst.nl/) explains clearly [that you should pay your tax in the Netherlands if you live there](http://www.belastingdienst.nl/wps/wcm/connect/bldcontenten/belastingdienst/individuals/tax_arrangements/income_from_abroad/income_from_abroad) (and also stated [here](http://www.belastingdienst.nl/wps/wcm/connect/bldcontenten/belastingdienst/individuals/moving_internationally/immigration/immigration_and_tax_issues/)):

> If you live in the Netherlands, you must state your complete worldwide income in your tax return. Your income from abroad is also part of your worldwide income (for example income from employment or foreign property).

There are some [agreements with other countries](http://www.belastingdienst.nl/wps/wcm/connect/bldcontenten/belastingdienst/individuals/tax_arrangements/income_from_abroad/regulations_to_avoid_double_taxation/regulations_to_avoid_double_taxation) to avoid double taxation.

When you immigrate you will have to do [several things](http://www.belastingdienst.nl/wps/wcm/connect/bldcontenten/belastingdienst/individuals/moving_internationally/immigration/what_do_you_have_to_do_if_you_immigrate/), the things related to working are:

- Obtain a *Citizen service number*:

  > You will be given this number by the local authorities where you live. The municipal authority will pass on your details to us.
- *Account number*:

  > you will need an account with a Dutch bank.